# Accepting the Answer of an Optimization Algorithm that has not Converged

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization

**Is there a popular consensus on accepting the solution from an optimization algorithm that has not converged?**

Suppose you let an optimization algorithm (e.g. gradient descent) run for many hours, and in the end it tells you that "convergence has not been reached".

On one hand, you would think that it might be unwise to accept a solution from an optimization algorithm that has not converged, for it might be unstable. But the other hand, the optimization algorithm would have still done a lot of work exploring the response surface, and it still might find a point that is better than random guessing, despite not having reached convergence. Also, you could use this solution from the optimization algorithm and judge it yourself? E.g. In a machine learning context, you accept the model parameter values that came from the un-converged optimization algorithm, and see how this model performs in terms of error rates on your data?

**In short - is it illogical to accept a solution from an optimization algorithm that has not converged?**

From a Machine Learning perspective -  this strikes me as an interesting problem : many times, a machine learning model based on the solution returned by a *converged optimization algorithm* might still not be "ideal", i.e. perform poorly ("overfitting" the data - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)).

**Thus: If a converged solution has the potential to perform poorly in real life - does this mean that perhaps a un-converged solution might have the potential to perform well in real life?**

I would be curious to hear everyone's thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: Presumably it would depend on **why** it told you that "convergence has not been reached"?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Are there several reasons as to why "convergence has not been reached"? I thought there is mainly one reason, i.e. the algorithm couldn't converge because the number of iterations were too small? thank you!